# Could not locate RequestBody converter in retrofit

Tags: android, xml, gson, retrofit

My API response can have both XML and JSON response. To adhere that I created a custom converter factory which takes in both as

```
public class QualifiedTypeConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

private final Converter.Factory jsonFactory;
private final Converter.Factory xmlFactory;

QualifiedTypeConverterFactory(Converter.Factory jsonFactory, Converter.Factory xmlFactory) {
    this.jsonFactory = jsonFactory;
    this.xmlFactory = xmlFactory;
}

@Override
public @Nullable Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(
        Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation instanceof Json) {
            return jsonFactory.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
        }
        if (annotation instanceof Xml) {
            return xmlFactory.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Annotations defined as

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Xml {
}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Json {
}
```

The retrofit object is created as

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@RetrofitNoIntercepter
fun provideRetrofit(
    @OkHttpNoIntercepter
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(
             QualifiedTypeConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create(), SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create()))
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL.plus("/"))
        .client(okHttpClient).build()
}
```

And this is my API interface

```
interface AdobeApi {

@Json
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST
suspend fun register(
    @Url url: String,
    @Header("X-Device-Info") device: String,
    @Body adobeStatement: AdobeStatement
): DeviceRegistrationInfo
```

When I run the app I get these errors

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class adobepass.data.remote.model.request.AdobeStatement (parameter #3)


Could not locate RequestBody converter for class adobepass.data.remote.model.request.AdobeStatement.
2023-09-08 13:46:25.433  3788-3788  System.err              com.mse.monumentalsnetwork           W    Tried:
2023-09-08 13:46:25.433  3788-3788  System.err              com.mse.monumentalsnetwork           W     * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
2023-09-08 13:46:25.433  3788-3788  System.err              com.mse.monumentalsnetwork           W     * adobepass.data.di.QualifiedTypeConverterFactory
```

The data class is

```
@Serializable
data class AdobeStatement(
@Expose
@SerializedName("software_statement")
val statement: String)
```

Comment: Could you try overriding `Converter.Factory#requestBodyConverter(Type, Annotation[], Annotation[], Retrofit)` instead? Maybe Retrofit is only calling that method (whose default implementation returns `null`)?